# Is there a memory limit for User Code Deployment on Hazelcast Cloud? (free version)

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-cloud

I'm currently playing with Hazelcast Cloud. My use case requires me to upload 50mb of jar file dependencies to Hazelcast Cloud servers. I found out that the upload seems to give up after about a minute or so. I get an upload rate of about 1mb a second, it drops after a while and then stops. I have repeated it a few times and the same thing happens.

Here is the config code I'm using:

```java
Clientconfig config = new ClientConfig();
ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig = 
    new ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig();

// added many jars here...  
clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addJar("jar dependancy path..");
clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addJar("jar dependancy path..");
clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addJar("jar dependancy path..");

clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.setEnabled(true);
config.setUserCodeDeploymentConfig(clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig);

ClientNetworkConfig networkConfig = new ClientNetworkConfig();

networkConfig.setConnectionTimeout(9999999); // i.e. don't timeout
networkConfig.setConnectionAttemptPeriod(9999999); // i.e. don't timeout

config.setNetworkConfig(networkConfig);
```

Any idea what's the cause, maybe there's a limit on the free cloud cluster?

Comment: It its the same thing happens on the paid version, however reduced the dependancies down to 20mb at it seems ok.

Comment: @Oliv thanks for editting and fixing the mistakes in my grammer, I was pretty tired when I wrote it!

Comment: You're still tired: grammer -> grammar :)

Comment: Thankyou for your corrections, I'm sure there will be more for you in the future lol, I believe I have undiagnosed Dyslexia, i'm good with abstract patterns etc but bad with spelling, either that or I a brain which naturally allocates much more resources to fuzzy pattern matching, meaning that rigid rules require more focus for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the smaller jar because this feature, the client user code upload, was designed for a bit different use cases:

> 1. You have objects that run on the cluster via the clients such as Runnable, Callable and Entry Processors.
> 2. You have new or amended user domain objects (in-memory format of the IMap set to Object) which need to be deployed into the cluster.

Please see more info [here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.5/manual/html-single/index.html#client-user-code-deployment-beta).